# Hiding team colors in usernames

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a minigame in Minecraft that is built upon not knowing what role other people are (kind of like a social deduction game). However, since teams are required for the game to function, a player can simply look in the tab menu and see the colors of every person, ruining the game. Is there a way to overwrite the colors of the names?

I can't change the team colors to the same, as the game uses the `killedByTeam.<color>`  objective to function

Comment: Couldn't you just change the colour of the names to be white or the same colour?

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: I can't change the team colors to the same, as the game uses the killedByTeam.<color> objective to function.

The version is Java 1.16.1

Comment: According to 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/g6r90b/how_to_set_team_colors_to_hex_codes_using_team/ this may work: `/team modify <team> displayName {"text" : "<text>", "color" : "#<hex>"}`

Comment: @towe That only changes the team’s display name colour, not the colour of player names on that team.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the follow command and replace the parts to what is what.

```
/team modify <team> displayName {"text" : "<text>", "color" : "#<hex>"}
```

Use the player kills scoreboard and use a execute command to see what team they are on.  Make a scoreboard dummy type for each team and depending on what team the player is on increase the team scoreboard.  I hope this helps.